# Is this code sample really returning the right parameterized types?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I've read the [Beautiful code with Google Collections, Guava and static imports](http://codemunchies.com/2009/10/beautiful-code-with-google-collections-guava-and-static-imports-part-1/) article about Java collections, and the following snippet got my attention:

```
Map<String, Map<Long, List<String>>> map = Maps.newHashMap();
```

The thing is, I don't understand how it's possible that the `newHashMap` method can return a `Map<String,Map<Long, List<String>>>`. How did they write this code? When did it became possible? I lived under the impression that you need to explicitly declare the generics parameters in the constructor call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare generic parameters on a method call, not just a whole class.  If you look at the source for that method:

```
public static <K, V> HashMap<K, V> newHashMap() {
    return new HashMap<K, V>();
}
```

You'll see it declares two generic parameters, K and V and declares the result to be a Map.  The compiler is smart enough to figure out K and V from the LHS expression.  In your case, K is `String` and V is `Map<Long, List<String>>`

Comment: Is this "figuring out" something new? Or has it been here all the time?

Comment: @Geo Its "new" as of Java 5.  I'm not sure what you mean otherwise.

Comment: I always instantiated the generic classes like: `Whatever<WhateverType> var = new Whatever<WhateverType>()`. I wasn't aware that `Whatever<WhateverType> var = new Whatever()` was legal.

Comment: @Geo That is a "literal" declaration.  The results are different when you declare a variable to be the result of a method invocation.

Comment: @Geo As an aside, your syntax *should* be legal in Java 7 with the new "Type Inference" JSR: http://www.javac.info/Inference.html

Comment: It seems I have some more reading to do on generics. Thanks guys!

Comment: JDK 7 looks as if it will require a "diamond" syntax: `Whatever<WhateverType> var = new Whatever<>();`. I don't really understand why that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source. All this method does is provides a nice shortcut:

```
public static <K, V> HashMap<K, V> newHashMap() {
  return new HashMap<K, V>();
}
```

This will work for any arguments because HashMap itself is generic.

Comment: True, it provides a shortcut. But why isn't it `Map<whatever> map = Maps.newHashMap<whatever>`?

Comment: @Geo - I don't understand what you mean by your comment

Comment: Say, this example: `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()`. Is it legal to write `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList()`? I remember needing to explicitly mention the parameter on both sides of the equal sign.

Comment: @Geo That declaration is different from invoking a method with generic parameters.

Comment: It's legal but will generate an unchecked warning. The difference between this and above is that above uses a generic method to instantiate your class. In your case the method would be `public static <T> ArrayList<T> newArrayList() { return new ArrayList<T>(); }` and you'd be able to write `List<String> myList = newArrayList();`

Comment: Literal generic method call is: `Maps.<Whatever>newHashMap()`.

Comment: @Tom - yes, but that's only needed when compiler can't figure out what the parameterized types should be.